# 3 Stacked DIVs to fit screen height?

Tags: html, css

Trying to stack 3 DIVs vertically, so that the top DIV is 25% of screen height, middle is 50%, and bottom is 25%, but they seem to extend the screen and I end up having a scrollbar.

```css
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
 width: 100%;
 height: 25%;
 background: #464646;
}

#middle {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
 margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
 min-width: 657px;
 height: 50%;
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:middle;
}

#bottom {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
 height: 25%;
 background: #988056;
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"><img src="logo.png"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: By default `padding` increases the computed `width`/`height`. You could add `box-sizing: border-box` to elements in order to make UAs calculate `height`/`width` of boxes including `padding` and `border`.

Answer (score 3):

As Hashem mentions in a comment above, `box-sizing: border-box` is considered best practice nowadays. Add the following to your CSS and you should be good to go:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[Here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) is a good read-up for you.

That said, if you are working on an existing product and have lots of legacy code that would be broken if you did this, you need to work around the margins and paddings on your site sections, they add height, and that makes it all add up to more than 100%.

And if you are uncomfortable with that as well, look up [`flex-box`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) layout. Only works in modern browsers though, so don't do it if you need old IE support.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the padding that you have added to **middle** and **bottom** divs.

The `width` and `height` styles always specify the width/height of textual area i.e. width/height of the **"div's content"** and they do **NOT** include the `padding` value. The padding is an **extra space** added *apart from the width/height*.

Try the following, and it should give you the desired results:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"><img src="logo.png"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body,html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #464646;
}

#middle {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  min-width: 657px;
  height: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: #988056;
}
```

Working [LIVE](http://jsfiddle.net/mc4gao0r/).

Answer (score 0):

The CSS [flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) module is especially made to handle requirements like this.

You can use the [`flex-grow`](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex-grow/) property:

> The flex-grow property is a sub-property of the Flexible Box Layout module.
>
> IT defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.
>
> For example, if all items have flex-grow set to 1, every child will set to an equal size inside the container. If you were to give one of the children a value of 2, that child would take up twice as much space as the others.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body {
  height: 100%;
}
#container{
  -webkit-display:flex;
  -moz-display:flex;
  -ms-display:flex;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction:column;
  -moz-flex-direction:column;
  -ms-flex-direction:column;
  flex-direction:column;
  height:100%;
}
#top {
  -webkit-flex:1;
  -moz-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;
  flex:1;
 background: #464646;
}

#middle {
  -webkit-flex:2;
  -moz-flex:2;
  -ms-flex:2;
  flex:2;
  background:dodgerblue;
}

#bottom {
  -webkit-flex:1;
  -moz-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;
  flex:1;
 background: #988056;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="top"></div>
 <div id="middle"></div>
 <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

In this scenario, since you're concerned about screen height, you might want to investigate the 'vh' css rule.

For instance, if you wanted to stack your top, middle, and bottom evenly, you could do it with pure css:

```
#top, #bottom, #middle {
    height: 32vh;
}
```

Or, as pertains to the question:

```
#top { height: 25vh; }
#middle { height: 50vh; }
#bottom { height 24vh; } /*24 vh so you have a little wiggle room*/
```

Examine here:

```css
body { margin : 0; padding: 0}
div { border: #ccc solid 1px; }
#top { height: 25vh; }
#middle { height: 50vh; }
#bottom { height: 24vh; } 
/*24 vh so you have a little wiggle room*/
```

```html
    <div id="top">top</div>
    <div id="middle">middle</div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```

Comment: Why on earth should you go with this? viewport percentage lengths are pointless in this particular case. Besides, using `24vh` instead of `25vh` is not the proper way to solve the issue.

Comment: OP asked for percentage of screen height.  Is the viewport not the screen?  And, what is the "proper way to solve the issue"?

Comment: In this case `25%` percentage value is equal to `25vh` since the `html` and `body` have `height` of `100%` of the viewport. And the proper way is to change the box model by `box-sizing` so that the UA will include `padding` into computed `height`. Using `vh` unit is not the case, the problem is caused by adding `padding` which you did not mention it at all.

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  But shouldn't he just change the box-sizing on those particular elements rather than the entire document as @PerSalbark proposed?

Comment: Either works. However targeting all elements `* {...}` may or may not meet the OP's need since it may affect other elements having both an explicit `width`/`height` and `padding`/`border`. But generally, [it is recommended](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) to do so, not by me.